# Texto não fica dentro da div

Tags: html, css

Estou fazendo treinando float em html, porém tive um problema digitei um texto aleatório e o texto não coube dentro da div, o que poderia ser, se eu digito algo não deveria ficar dentro da minha div ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Teste</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">

        #principal{
            width: 920px;
        }

        .noticia{
            background: #e5e5e5;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 140px;
            margin: 7px;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="princiapal">
        <div class="noticia">
            <p>
                iasdhaoidhsoiashdoiashdoiashdoiashdoiashdoisahdoisahdoisahdosadoiasdhoiashdo
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Esse 'texto' esta sendo tratado como uma palavra por não ter espaços, acho que se você utilizar o css `word-wrap: break-word;` deve resolver

Comment: Tente https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989546/wrap-a-text-within-only-two-lines-inside-div